# addClass between 2 buttons like radio button using Jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, addclass

I have 2 `<span>` which I want to make like radio buttons but a bit different than radio buttons.

For example.

```
<span>Button1</span>
<span>Button2</span>
```

When an user clicks on Button1 then `addClass '.active'` to Button1's span.
In the meantime, when user click on Button2 then remove the Button1's span `'.active'` and 
add it to Button2's span. So far, this is similar to a radio button. But I need to remove the `.active` when a user clicks on the same button which already has `.active` exists.

My problem is I don't know how to switch the active class between the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Dumitru Chirutac answer :

you can fix his answer to have the correct behavior with the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){ //use the correct selector for your html
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');       
        }
    });
});
```

This way you check if the current if already active. If yes remove active. If not use it as a toggle.

[updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XUN6P/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

**HTML**

```
<span class="btn">Button 1</span>
<span class="btn">Button 2</span>
<span class="btn">Button 3</span>
<span class="btn">Button 4</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn').click(function(){
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');       
   });
});
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XUN6P/)

Comment: They stay active when you reclick them, this doesn't work. `But I need to remove the .active when user click on the same button which already has .active exists.`